# Cannot edit a file created in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, io, windows-phone-8.1, storage

I created a file in Windows Phone 8.1 using the following code.

```
await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.CreateFileAsync("Test.txt");
```

And I am launching the file in default app (Office Word) using the below code,

```
var file = await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.CreateFileAsync("Test.txt");
await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
```

When editing the file and trying to save, it shows error.

"The changes can't be saved because the file is set to read-only." How can I create a file that can be modified by end user.